jest-worker for Node issue with resolving ESM modules
I have a Node script which uses jest-worker. I am also using .mjs files/ESM modules in Node v22.
I am having a issue with jest-worker and getting it to take ESM modules. For Jest, I need to resolve the module. So for ESM, I am doing:
  import { createRequire } from 'node:module';
  const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
    
  const auditRepo = require.resolve('./lib/audit-repo.mjs');  
                                                              
  const init = async () => {                                  
    const jestOptions = {                                     
      forkOptions: { silent: false },                         
      exposedMethods: [                                       
        'processRepo',                                        
      ],                                                      
    };                                                        
                                                              
    const worker = new JestWorker(auditRepo, jestOptions);  

However, I get the error:

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/one/github/atlas-ui-audit/src/lib/audit-repo.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of /home/one/github/atlas-ui-audit/src/lib/audit-repo.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

So, I changed it to using a dynamic import but had no success with the below error:
  const auditRepo = await import('./lib/audit-repo.mjs');   
                                                              
  const init = async () => {                                  
    const jestOptions = {                                     
      forkOptions: { silent: false },                         
      exposedMethods: [                                       
        'processRepo',                                        
      ],                                                      
    };                                                        
                                                              
    const worker = new JestWorker(auditRepo, jestOptions);    


TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')
at new Worker (/home/one/github/atlas-ui-audit/node_modules/jest-worker/build/index.js:120:20)
at init (file:///home/one/github/atlas-ui-audit/src/exec-audit.mjs:28:18)
at file:///home/one/github/atlas-ui-audit/src/exec-audit.mjs:50:1

How can I get jest-worker to work with ESM modules in this fashion? Or is it even possible?
Note: I would like to keep this native .mjs files without rollup and babel.

The error refers to require that the lib uses  , not your own require.resolve(), which is ok. import() isn't a substitute because auditRepo is supposed to be module path, not a module itself. Jest already heavily relies on Babel, so this wouldn't be a problem there. If you're using Jest's lib in non-test context then that's what you get. It wasn't advertised for anything but tests I believe

hmmm... interesting. I do not see any mention of for tests context https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-worker

The presence of "jest" in the title and https://github.com/jestjs/jest as the home page strongly suggest that. Any way, Jest still relies on cjs for historical reasons, so this is expected

After doing some research, they make it clear you can cherry pick features of Jest to use  in stand alone packages. I found this issue where native ESM support is being worked on since 2020 https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/9430

Did you try —experimental-require-module? https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#loading-ecmascript-modules-using-require

—experimental-require-module did it, thanks
